# Timeout in uploading a big file to google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm having trouble uploading large files to Google Cloud Storage. I successfully uploaded a 700MB file, but when I tried a 5GB text file, it threw the following exception. I was unable to find a solution with a Google search.

The problem is in the main method of a simple java class.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:312)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:350)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:893)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:850)
......
```

Answer (score 1):

[Getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608499/getting-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-connection-timed-out-in-android) it looks like you may need to jump up your connection timeout setting.  The link is for android, but the same thing applies, and it's implemented exactly the same.

Comment: In the java client library for google cloud storage, there is no where to set the connection timeout length.

Comment: Storage.Objects.Insert insertObject = storage.objects().insert(bucketName, objectMetadata, mediaContent);
insertObject.execute(); It seems no where to set the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

With larger files, especially on mobile devices and wireless connections, you're much more likely to have your uploads interrupted by a broken connection.  The solution to this is to make your upload resilient against broken connections.  Google Cloud Storage handles this using a technique called [Resumable Uploads](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques#resumable).  You'll need to make use of this technique so your application can recover from network issues.

Comment: It used resumable upload. By default, it is resumable upload.

Answer (score 1):

In Java SDK we have option to change the connection timeout and retry.

```
HttpTransportOptions transportOptions = StorageOptions.getDefaultHttpTransportOptions();
            transportOptions = transportOptions.toBuilder().setConnectTimeout(60000).setReadTimeout(60000)
                    .build();
var storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
    .setRetrySettings(RetrySettings.newBuilder().setMaxAttempts(2).build())
    .setTransportOptions(transportOptions)
    .setProjectId("project_id").build().getService();
```