# Drive.Files.Create.execute() java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to upload file using Drive.Files.Create api. It ran well but suddenly getting SocketTimeOut Exception after 10-15 request.

```
drive = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
              APPLICATION_NAME).build();
Drive.Files.Create insert = drive.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent);
insert.setUseContentAsIndexableText(true);
File f=insert.execute();
```

Exception StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1536)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithoutGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:545)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:417)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:427)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.ob.pdfparser.MyClass.uploadFile(MyClass.java:42)
    at com.ob.pdfparser.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:91)
```

**Usage Limit:**

> Queries
>
> requests/day  20 of 1,000,000,000
>
> requests/100seconds/user  1,000

Any Idea??

Answer (score 1):

Below thing worked

```
    Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(this.httpTransport, this.jsonFactory, this.credential).setHttpRequestInitializer(new HttpRequestInitializer() {@Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {

                credential.initialize(httpRequest);
                httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(300 * 60000);  // 300 minutes connect timeout
                httpRequest.setReadTimeout(300 * 60000);  // 300 minutes read timeout
}
}).setApplicationName("My Application").build();
```

Answer (score 0):

`SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` can be solved by defining a connection timeout or adjusting the timeout barrier so that it's more flexible on network delays. Other than that, you can also check what causes delays in your network because, as far as I know, this kind of error is a network connectivity issue and not a programming issue.

Complete explanation about this kind of error can be found in [java.net.SocketTimeoutException – How to Solve SocketTimeoutException](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/sockettimeoutexception/java-net-sockettimeoutexception-how-to-solve-sockettimeoutexception/) and this SO post - [Getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608499/getting-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-connection-timed-out-in-android) might also help.