# FirebaseAuthException: Timed out while making an API call: Read timed out

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit, socket-timeout-exception

I have an android project I've started working on that connects to a backend API. Both the backend and the client use Firebase Authentication. The problem is that I've been running into an issue when updating a user's custom claims on the backend (something that can't be done on the client for security reasons). I have a backend api that gets called from the Android app to update the claims appropriately (utilizing Firebase Admin SDK's FirebaseAuth.update() method), however whenever I try to do so, it throws a FirebaseAuthException with this as its (Throwable) cause without any delay (indicating that its not really a timeout issue):

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:981)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1434)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1038)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:754)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1623)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1528)
at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:308)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:36)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:149)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
at com.google.firebase.internal.ErrorHandlingHttpClient.send(ErrorHandlingHttpClient.java:96)
at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.AuthHttpClient.sendRequest(AuthHttpClient.java:75)
at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.AuthHttpClient.sendRequest(AuthHttpClient.java:69)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUserManager.post(FirebaseUserManager.java:351)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUserManager.updateUser(FirebaseUserManager.java:174)
at com.google.firebase.auth.AbstractFirebaseAuth$12.execute(AbstractFirebaseAuth.java:762)
at com.google.firebase.auth.AbstractFirebaseAuth$12.execute(AbstractFirebaseAuth.java:759)
at com.google.firebase.internal.CallableOperation.call(CallableOperation.java:36)
at com.google.firebase.auth.AbstractFirebaseAuth.updateUser(AbstractFirebaseAuth.java:740)
at com.shmoodle.firebase.dao.FirebaseAuthUserDaoImpl.update(FirebaseAuthUserDaoImpl.java:38)
at com.shmoodle.firebase.dao.FirebaseAuthUserDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$363e1231.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
at com.shmoodle.firebase.dao.FirebaseAuthUserDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$307685be.update(<generated>)
at com.shmoodle.consumer.service.ConsumerServiceImpl.initializeAccount(ConsumerServiceImpl.java:70)
at com.shmoodle.consumer.service.ConsumerServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$257bab2a.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687)
at com.shmoodle.consumer.service.ConsumerServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4b5fd59.initializeAccount(<generated>)
at com.shmoodle.consumer.api.controller.ConsumerController.initializeConsumer(ConsumerController.java:50)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at com.shmoodle.firebase.utility.FirebaseAuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(FirebaseAuthenticationTokenFilter.java:49)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

NOTE: What's interesting is that it only throws this exception when the api controller is called via HTTP (Retrofit) from the Android app, and NOT when the same controller is called from Postman. When the api is called from Postman, the call is completed successfully without a hitch.

I'm seriously confused on what to do here. I've found related issues on StackOverflow to have rather obscure answers (reference: [Getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608499/getting-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-connection-timed-out-in-android)), and none related to the use of Firebase Admin SDK on the backend. Does anyone know what to do here? I'm considering abandoning use of Firebase's custom claims feature as this is causing it to be more trouble than its worth.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Since this appears to be a network issue, not a programming issue, I found the answer is to simply try the call multiple times as its not guaranteed to work on the first attempt. So I changed the original method:

```
@Override
public void update(UserRecord.UpdateRequest request) throws FirebaseAuthException {
    firebaseAuth.updateUser(request);
}
```

to:

```
@Override
public void update(UserRecord.UpdateRequest request) throws FirebaseAuthException {
    FirebaseAuthException firebaseAuthException = null;
    boolean success = false;
    for (int retries = 0; retries < 3; retries++) {
        try {
            firebaseAuth.updateUser(request);
            success = true;
            break;
        } catch (FirebaseAuthException e) {
            firebaseAuthException = e;
            // connection timed out...let's try again
        }
    }
    if (!success) {
        throw(firebaseAuthException);
    }
}
```

And now it works properly. I'll leave this response here for others who encounter the same problem.