# How to resolve org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException in Android?

Tags: java, android, web-services, exception, connection-timeout

I am working on service related application.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 15000000);
            HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpClient.getParams(),true);

            String str_Server_Host = Control_PWD_Server_Name();
            String requestEnvelope = String.format(envelope_oe);
            // HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(str_Server_Host);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(str_Server_Host);
            httpPost.setHeader("SOAPAction",
                    "http://tempuri.org/updateTransportStatus");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestEnvelope));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            String str = Html.fromHtml(line).toString();
```

This is the exception I am getting:

```
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /10.64.0.184:9092 timed out
```

How to resolve above exception in android? please give any suggestion or related senario.

Comment: is this address accessible from your phone??

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075506/http-connection-timeout-on-android-not-working?rq=1

Comment: Hi Vipul address not accessible my phone its showing connection problem exactly.

Comment: have u add internet permission in manifest file

Comment: Hi All ,Thank you very much for kind support issue is clear(network issue).